# How to get value more 320 in iPhone by panning UIView using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to show numbers (0 to 500) by panning left to right and same by panning right to left (500 to 0) in iPhone. The problem is, since width of iPhone is 320px, i can't show more than the number 320.

please help.

Display sequential change in numbers from 0 to 500 and vice versa(500 to 0).

Comment: Multiply by 2 ? You'll get [0-640]

Comment: Multiplying by 2 or 1.5635, We can't get sequential numbers from 0 to 500

Comment: What exactly is the question? And I think you would have to describe some of your preconditions.

Comment: Just to correct @vijaikumar multiply with, 1.5625.

Answer (score 2):

You could always multiply the offset by 2 :)

Comment: Or by 1.5625 if you want [0,500]

Comment: yes, a simple multiplication of 1.5625 (= 500/320) will give you the desired number (cast it with an int for an integer value)

Comment: @rdurand Multiplying by 2 or 1.5635, We can't get sequential numbers from 0 to 500

Comment: @vijaikumar: well, there's no way you can increase the screen resolution, so you won't get all the numbers from 0 to 500.. The best you can get is 320 numbers between 0 and 500.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers don't need to all be on the screen at the same time, you could use a `UIScrollView` where the width of the `contentSize` is 500 point (then pan left and right to show the extra details past the 320 points)

See Apple Docs:  [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)